# Why is this a Cross Domain Request and how to solve it?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, cross-domain

Rendering the following HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Loading data</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js?2.7.4"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.csv.js?2.7.4"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    @import url("style.css?1.10.0");
    </style>
</head>
<body>  
    <div align="center">
        <h1>Loading data</h1>
    </div>
    <div id='chart' align="center">
        <svg class="svg_area" width="800" height="400">
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var data=[];
    d3.csv("coordinates.csv",
                function(rows){
                    var svg=d3.select("svg");
                    svg.selectAll("circle").data(rows).enter()
                        .append("circle")
                            .attr("cx",function(d){return d.x;})
                            .attr("cy",function(d){return d.y;})
                            .attr("r","10")
                            .attr("fill","green");
                }
           );       
</script>
```

it arises the following error in the JavaScript console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load     file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Engineer/Ongoing/…0Visualization/Slides/1)%20Introduction%20to%20d3/coordinates.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.d3.xhr @ d3.js:434

Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Engineer/Ongoing/…0Visualization/Slides/1)%20Introduction%20to%20d3/coordinates.csv'. @ d3.js:434
```

my question is: why is this a Cross Domain Request?

As long as I understand, the javascript's source domain is C://, and the .csv lies on the same filesystem. So why the browser recognizes this as "cross domain" ?

Which is the cleanest way to fix it?

Comment: Ajax simply doesn't work with the file protocol, it's intended for the http protocol. Download WAMP server or something similar.

Comment: Two files served in file:// are considered having different origins.